# Popup with fadeout delay ... and more

Tags: popup, fadeout

Im searching for a popup which will appear on click, then fadeout on delay, but will restart if clicked once more at any given time.
I found  [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tbleckert/RcL5y/)  which is close, but unsure how to convert it to a popup.

my script:

```
<html>
<title> Smile For Me! </title>
<head>
</head>
<script>

function mypopup1() { 
var popup = document.getElementById("mypopup1");     
popup.classList.toggle("show");
} 

</script>

<style>
    .popup {  
    position: relative; 
    display: block; 
    top:20vw; 
    left:0vw; 
    cursor: pointer;   
    user-select: none;
    }
    
    span.pics {
    top: 2vw;  
    left: 3vw; 
    width:20vw; 
    height:25vw;  
    background-color: #FFF;  
    background-size:100%; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;  
    }   
    
    .popup .pic1{  
    visibility: hidden; 
    position: absolute; 
    background-image:url(https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-XBZOVPjdFBA/UTSJuexroVI/AAAAAAAACyE/0Z6qaxPyXmY/s640/smiley-face-wallpaper-0011.jpg); 
    }
    

.popup .show {  
visibility: visible; 
}   

    
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="popup" onclick="mypopup1()"> Smile <span  class="pics pic1" id="mypopup1"><center></span></button>               

</body>
</html>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.